# Hardhat deployer in tests best practice

Tags: solidity, truffle, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I changed from truffle to hardhat for testing contracts.
But I can't figure out how to change the deployer account for the local tests within the tests...

In truffle:
`aContract = await contract.deployed(anyParameter, {from: deployAccount})`

What would be the corresponding line for hardhat(parameters + deployer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

```
factory = await Factory.connect(deployAccount).deploy(parameters);
```

Full deployment:

```
[owner, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
const Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Factory");
factory = await Factory.connect(addr1).deploy(parameters);
await factory.deployed();
```

Comment: Hi when I do so I get the error: `Error: invalid signer (argument="signer", value="0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.4.1)` 

Normal interactions with contracts after deployment works perfectly fine this way.

Comment: Ok got it... the returns of getSigners() is not an address but a object... (I taked the addresses in the addr1 ...)